# Show that $R/\langle a_i\rangle$ is torsion

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Robert Ash Abstract Algebra chapter 4, section 4.6.5, there is this statement: 'Now assume that $R$ is PID, and decompose $M$ as in (4.6.3), where $a_1,\dotsc,a_r$ are nonzero and $a_{r+1}=\dotsb=a_n=0$. Each module $R/\langle a_i\rangle$, $1 \leq i \leq r$, is torsion...'

I don't understand why $R/\langle a_i\rangle$ is torsion. I try to prove it but I cannot. The following is my proof:

Aim: Prove $\operatorname{Tor}(R/\langle a_i\rangle)=R/\langle a_i\rangle$.

Let $x \in \operatorname{Tor}(R/\langle a_i\rangle)$. Then there exists non zero $r \in R$ such that $rx=0$, which is $r(s+Ra_i)=Ra_i=rs+Ra_i$. Then we obtain $rs \in Ra_i$. Then I stuck at here. Can anyone check whether I am going in the right direction?

Comment: For $x \in R/\langle a_i\rangle$, what is $a_i\cdot x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are approaching the problem 'backwards'.  You want to show that given any $x \in R/\langle a_i\rangle$, there exists $r \in R$ such that $rx = 0$.  This is easy: for any $x$, take $r = a_i$.

Comment: So this prove RHS is subset of LHS right? Regarding the LHS is subset of RHS, I just have to quote since $Tor(M) \subset M$, hence the inclusion holds, is this correct?

Comment: @Idonknow: Exactly; $\mathrm{Tor}(M)$ is a sub-module of $M$ by definition, so there is nothing to prove in that direction.